# How do I call the function from within the function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a build as below. When I click the button, I want to send a request to the function it is in with the value of the textbox without refreshing the page. I didn't get the value of the textbox I think I'm making a punctuation error. How can I run the function without refreshing the page by resubmitting the domain name to the function I am in?

I am currently getting this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: getDomain is not defined

```
var getDomain = (domainName) => {
              console.log(domainName);
              let txtDomain = document.createElement('input');
              txtDomain.type="text";
              txtDomain.setAttribute("id","txtDomain");
              queryDiv.appendChild(txtDomain);
              
              let btnDomain = document.createElement('button');
              btnDomain.innerHTML="Sorgula";
              btnDomain.setAttribute("onclick","getDomain('txtDomain.value'); return false;");
              queryDiv.appendChild(btnDomain);

};
```

Comment: Extra double quote on line 2?

Comment: thanks i fix it. but problem is continues

Comment: Could you explain the intent of this function? It looks like the intent is to create a textbox and a button, then when the button is clicked it should create another textbox and a button. However, there's a lot of problems with that: reuse of an ID, the `domainName` argument isn't used, the onclick code wouldn't work, queryDiv is not defined, extra quote character, etc.

Comment: Looks like you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qcgksfv2/

Comment: You can ignore the duplication. my question is just to send a request to the function with the text and button that I created dynamically.

Comment: @ChrisG It's very close to what I want, but how do I do it without refreshing the page?

Comment: Are the buttons inside a <form>? If so you need to prevent the default event: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/te1yhocq/

Comment: How do I run it without refreshing the page? @ChrisG

Comment: Clicking a button submits the form, and if the form doesn't have an action or method attribute, it by default reloads the page. If you want to prevent this, refer to the additional `e.preventDefault()` line in my second fiddle. If you're talking about something else, please explain more clearly, ideally with a [mre] in the question.